# Why can't I upload to Testflight using Jenkins Fastlane but I can using terminal on MacOS?

Tags: jenkins, testflight, fastlane

I use the fastlane beta command in Jenkins to upload to Testflight/apple for our app. For some reason, it hangs during the Jenkins build process on step [Transporter]: DBG-X:   parameter EnableJWTForAllCalls = false. When I use the same Jenkins command (fastlane beta) using terminal on the server itself, it works just fine. I updated the path on the Jenkins node to be the same path as the build server but it still hangs. I am not sure what else can be different.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I also noticed its using operation named: lookupSoftwareForBundleId instead of authenticateForTransportDiscovery